# How can I get injected javascript code executed in local scope in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a html document loaded in an iframe.
I have developed some popup-menu code in javascript for that document and I inject the code into the iframe from the main document.

But my code does not work in the iframe because it uses the "`document`" object and that surprisingly refers to the main document and not the iframe document.

I also play around content selection and there I need `window.getSelection()` which goes back to the main document's selections and I'd need `window.frames[0].getSelection()` instead.

Am I doing sth wrong?
Is there any simple solution to overcome this?

**UPDATE:**(clarification)
As Bergi pointed out, my question is about how to run correctly injected javascript code to get local scope and not global scope in the iframe?
So I do *not* have to rewrite  `document`'s and `window`'s in the code...

**UPDATE:**
(skeleton of my html)

```
<html>
  <head></head> <!-- script launches on jquery's $(document).ready -->
  <body>
    <iframe>
    [
      <body>
        ...
        <script></script> <!-- code injected here from the code (appended to the body) -->
      </body>
    ]
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script goes like this (using jquery):

```
$(function(){
$('iframe').load(function(){

var $doc = $('iframe').contents();
var $head = $('head', $doc);
$head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/book-popup-menu.css" />');

var $body = $('body', $doc);
$body.append(' \
    <div id="popup"> \
    </div> \
');
$body.append(' \
    <script type="text/javascript"> \
              console.log(document.body);// it still displays the global body \
            </script> \
');
});
});
```

**UPDATE**: [A fiddle demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/eBrFT/)

Comment: Depends on how you inject the code into the iframe - show us that snippet, please. If you're doing it wrong, the code is still executed in the global scope of the parent document.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I've updated my question as you asked.

Comment: And you say that the `/scripts/book-popup-menu.js` is executed with `document` pointing to the parent frame's one?

Comment: yes, exactly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on yet, but I can confirm the problem.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I've just figured! `document.createElement(...)` working in the background of `.append(...)` does not change document to the iframe when needed therefore the global scope. Vanilla javascript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found an answer!

If you append code with jQuery like `$body.append('<script>')` then the '' element gets created by `document.createElement('script')` thus will be part of the global document. Even after it is inserted to the iframe document, **it will execute in the global namespace**.

So the solution is -- taking advantage of this fabulous solution:([Injecting Javascript to Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353028/injecting-javascript-to-iframe?rq=1)) -- to fall back to vanilla javascript:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){

    var $doc = $('iframe').contents();
    var $head = $('head', $doc);
    $head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/book-popup-menu.css" />');

    var $body = $('body', $doc);
    $body.append('<div id="popup"></div>');// non-javascript content works fine

    var doc = $('iframe').contents()[0]; // doc = $doc[0] does not work for some reason... 

    var script = doc.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.textContent = "console.log(document.body)"; // this will be iframe's body
    $body[0].appendChild(script1); // $body.append(...) does not work
});
```

Comment: I think you could as well use something like `$("#popup", $doc).html("<script>…")`, that should not create an element in jQuery's context.