# [codeplayer]How to find element inside of an iframe when the iframe content was dynamic loaded with javascript from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

As a challange of mine, i decided to do a little Code Player like jsfiddle, i have done all, but my problem come when i try to exec JS, when i try to call an element inside the iframe like this:

```
document.getElementById("hola").innerHTML="nohola";
```

It just says:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

There's a live demo: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/no33v8n7/)

How i can inject js into the iframe and call elements inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `script` tag is created by the `document` object of your main document.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
```

Which will make the javascript inside it scoped to the main document. You have to create it using the `document` object of the `iframe`, so that the javascript will be scoped to the `iframe`.

You can access the `iframe` document through the `contentWindow.document` property like this:

[**Check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/no33v8n7/1/)

```
function runJs() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('resultIframe');
      var frameDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var body = $('body', frameDoc);
      var code = $('#codeJs').find('textarea').val();
      var script = frameDoc.createElement("script");           // not document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      script.textContent = code; 
      body[0].appendChild(script); 
}
```

Also see these answers

- [getElementById from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896365/2300466)
- [Inject javascript in local scope of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424498/2300466)